# Ignore certain cucumber tags during Jenkins Run

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, scenarios, feature-file, atdd

I have a couple feature files that comprise of:

```
@Feature1
Feature 1
    
@Tag1 @Tag2
Scenario: Scenario 1
```

---

```
@Feature2
Feature  2
    
@Tag1 @Tag3
Scenario: Scenario 2
```

I want to know how to run scenarios with @tag1 but not ones that also have @tag2(Run the scenario feature file in this scenario)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like this you can use to resolve your issue. tags={"@Tag1", "~@Tag2"}

Comment: @UnknownBeast How would this translate to Jenkins?

Comment: Use cucumber runner and in the cucumber options you need to provide this. If you are going to dynamically change the tags then use cucumber cli to achieve the same. If you face any issue then Let me know.